# Sharepoint List Exported to Excel - Columns are readonly

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-excel-2003

From a sharepoint list, I chose `Actions -> Export to Spreadsheet`, saved the `owssvr.iqy` file, opened this file, and tried editing entries in Excel.

When I try to edit any columns, I am shown: "The *xxxx* column is a read-only column that cannot be modified."

I did a Google, which suggested a couple of ideas:

- One [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220818075508/https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/) suggested using sysinternal's ProcMon to see what is happening. However, I didn't see the registry entries it suggested I should see.
- Another [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150511034703/http://geekswithblogs.net/EnderSoft/articles/excel-office-2003-documents-opening-as-read-only-in-sharepoint.aspx) suggested it could be something blocking an 'OPTIONS' request to the sharepoint server?
- Another link suggested it could be because I have SP3 of Excel 2003?
- Another [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310104022/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/838028) suggested checking the registry entries for `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Common\Internet\Server Cache`, but these entries looked OK?

```
    [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Common\Internet\Server Cache\https://xxxx.o2.com/sites/xxxx/]
    "Type"=dword:00000005
    "Protocol"=dword:00000003
    "Expiration"=hex(b):30,CD,6b,8a,c6,6a,ca,01
```

**Has anyone else seen this, and found a way around this?**

Answer (score 1):

I've always run into problems when dealing with the owssvr.iqy file.  I'm not really sure what the file is (something related to a query to sharepoint I think) but it's not really what you want to save.  When exporting to a spreadsheet I do the following (Excel 2007):

1. Actions -> Export to Spreadsheet
2. Open (opposed to Save)
3. Click 'enable' when prompted by the security warning
4. At this point you should have an Excel spreadsheet with the data from your list.  Save this spreadsheet.

This will create a linked spreadsheet.  You can update the data in your spreadsheet with the sharepoint server by clicking on options->refresh all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Michael. However, this doesn't seem to work in my case :-(

Answer (score 1):

Hotfix kb952608 seems to solve the problem according to:

> http://www.tekrum.net/excel-2003-sharepoint-list-read-only-column-problem

Answer (score 1):

After clicking *Open* you need to go to the *Properties* dialog and then uncheck the *Save Query* check box.

This would make your column editable.